# Django 3 vs Django 2

Tags: django, python-3.x

Is django 3 backward compatible with django 2? Are there any syntax changes in django 3 compared to django 2? Will i be able to follow django 2 tutorial on YouTube and be okay to apply it in django 3 as there are not many django 3 tutorials available?

Comment: No Django version is fully compatible with the previous one. In the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3-0) you can see what has changed.

Comment: I think release notes are the best place to look for your answer not SO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is django 3 backward compatible with django 2?

No Django version is *fully* backwards compatible with the previous one. In the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3-0), one can see what has changed. [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) is not compatible with [django-2.1](/questions/tagged/django-2.1), although in that case the changes are smaller, as is stated in the [*Django’s release process* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#official-releases):

> `A.B` is the feature release version number. Each version will be **mostly backwards compatible** with the previous release. **Exceptions** to this rule will be listed **in the release notes**.

---

> Are there any syntax changes in django 3 compared to django 2?

Not much, [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0) adds for example a [**`Sign`** expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.Sign), and the [**`CheckConstraint`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.CheckConstraint) is now supported for MySQL 8.0.16+, and there are some other features listed in the release notes. But this is simply extending on existing functionality.

> Will i be able to follow django 2 tutorial on YouTube and be okay to apply it in django 3 as there are not many django 3 tutorials available?

Likely **yes**. In case something is not working, you better look at the release notes, and see if that is impacted and try to fix it accordingly. However more sophisticated problems will often arise when you are more familiar with the Django framework.

Comment: There should be <comma> after first word of your answer, but I cannot edit post to add only one sign.

Comment: @404pio: no, it means that there is no Django version that is fully backwards compatible. It is thus *not* a *no* as an answer, it means that for all Django versions, there are modifications that makes it non-compatible with other Django versions.

Answer (score 7):

Django 3 is just an evolutionary step from Django 2.

It is not like Python 3 and Python 2.

Some amount of work may be required to port from Django 2 to 3 but much less than needed to port from Python 2 to 3.